# Why does .net modulo works different than windows calcuator for small numbers?

Tags: c#, calculator, modulo

Why does `1070 % 21,4` gives a different result in the windows calculator and .net?

(.Net result is 7.1....)

The result should always be `0`. I understand a difference with large numbers, but these small numbers should work, IMHO.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The .NET result _is not_ 7.1.It's 7.1 x 10^-14, or 0.000000000000071. And, if you're wondering "why is it 7.1 x 10^-14?" see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: It's 0 but resul type is double https://dotnetfiddle.net/tWUzhC

Comment: Small numbers are just as bad as big numbers when it comes to floating point maths - eg in .NET `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` is `false`.

Comment: My bad, I've missed the exponential number...

Comment: And it Always cool to read the Lippert serie of article [Floating Point Arithmetic](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/floating-point-arithmetic/page/2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its all in the docs for the % operator. Its floating point remainder, not modulo. If you want something compatible with Calculator use
[this function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ieeeremainder?view=netframework-4.7.2)

For example:

```
private static void ShowRemainders(double number1, double number2)
{
   var formula = $"{number1} / {number2}";
   var ieeeRemainder = Math.IEEERemainder(number1, number2);
   var remainder = number1 % number2;
   Console.WriteLine($"{formula,-16} (.IEEE) = {ieeeRemainder,18}");
   Console.WriteLine($"{formula,-16} (.NET)  = {remainder,18}");
}
```